# Retrieve image from database in c#

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

i have a table in my database in which contains an Image_ID, Image, Image_Name and Recipe_ID.

I am trying to edit these in a seperate form. So when a row in the dataGridView is selected it will open up in the edit form with the relevant areas filled out with data.

I am able to do it with all data apart from the Image. Obviously i need to somehow convert it as like i have done with the text fields but i have no idea on how to do so.

***Edit Image Row***

```
//Edit image row
        private void EditImageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                EditImageForm Image = new EditImageForm();

                Image.imageidTxt.Text = this.imageGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                //Image.picImg.Text = this.imageGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                Image.nameTxt.Text = this.imageGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                Image.recipeCombo.Text = this.imageGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

                Image.ShowDialog();
                loadImageTable();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the data type of the image ? Is it stored as a BLOB or varbinary in the database? And is your issue converting that back to a visual image?

Comment: @DavidOesterreich Image and its stored as Bytes. I have got my upload working but not able to retrieve it to view it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image is stored bytes, you can try something similar to the below to convert the bitmap to an Image type:

```
byte[] bitmap = this.imageGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;    
Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bitmap))
```

More info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx